# How to create a php function to update database on submit?

Tags: php, function

I created this function to update a database when the submit button is clicked. But it doesn't seem to work. The script is meant to draw the values of the user from the database using the login detail of the user through id and populate the forms. The function is to help update the details of the user when their is a change in the form text field.

Please, I need help debugging it.

```
libraries.php
function db(){ //handles database connection

//connect to the database server or die and spit out connection error
$conn = mysql_connect('localhost','root', '') or die("Cannot connect to the database server now". mysql_error());
//select database table or die and spit out database selection error
mysql_select_db('newbishop',$conn) or die("Error in selecting database now ".mysql_errno());
  return $conn;  
}


personalsettings.php
<?php
include_once('libraries.php'); // contains the database function
session_checker();

db();
$categoryid = $_SESSION['id'];
$select =  "SELECT * FROM users WHERE categoryid ='$categoryid' LIMIT 1";
$row1 = dbprocess ($select);
$rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($row1);
$pname1 = $rows['pname'];
$email1 = $rows['email'];
$user1 = $rows['user'];
$pass1 = $rows['pass'];
$salt1 = $rows['salt'];
$phone1 = $rows['phone'];
$accesslevel = $rows['accesslevel'];
$position = $rows['position'];

function update(){
   db(); // database function
   $pname = $_POST['pname'];
   $categoryid = $_POST['categoryid'];
   $email = $_POST['email'];
   $phone = $_POST['phone'];
   $user = $_POST['users'];
   $pass = $_POST['pass'];

   function createSalt(){
     $string = md5(uniqid(rand(), true));
     return substr($string, 0, 3);
   };

   $salt = createSalt();
   $hash = hash('sha256', $salt . $pass);

   $sql = "UPDATE users SET user=?,pass=?,salt=?,pname=?,email=?,phone=? WHERE categoryid=?";
   $q = $conn->prepare($sql);
   $q->execute(array($user,$hash,$salt,$pname,$email,$phone,$categoryid));
}

?>
```

the form
     
    Edit personal Settings

```
<input name="users" type="text" id="users" class="users" autocomplete="off" value="<?php echo $user1;  ?>" />

<input type="text" autocomplete="off" name="pass" id="pass" placeholder="Create password" class="passwd" value="<?php echo $pass;  ?>"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="salt" id="salt" value="<?php echo $salt1;  ?>"/>


    <input name="pname" type="text" id="lname" placeholder="Name of Group" class="input-block-level" value="<?php echo $pname1;  ?>"/>

   <input type="hidden" id="categoryselect" name="categoryselect"/> 
   <input name="categoryid" type="text" id="resultselect"   readonly class="input-block-level" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['id'];  ?>"/>


    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email Address" class="input-block-level" value="<?php echo $email1;  ?>"/>


    <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" placeholder="Enter Phone Number" class="input-block-level" value="<?php echo $phone1;  ?>"/>


    <input type="text" name="accesslevel" id="accesslevel" class="input-block-level" value="<?php echo $accesslevel;  ?>" readonly/>



    <input type="text" name="position" id="position" class="input-block-level" value="<?php echo $position;  ?>" readonly/>


    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-small btn-primary" name="register" id="register" value="Register" onclick="update()">Submit</button>
  </form>
```

Comment: Wow; a PHP question that doesn't make any of the usual mistakes!  However, SHA* is too fast for a password hash (it allows extremely rapid brute-forcing).  Instead, use bcrypt or scrypt or PBKDFv2.

Comment: what you done to debug it yourself? checked return values? right now your db operations seem to be assuming success.

Comment: Where is the part that would call this function? Also, are you sure you want to declare the createSalt function inside the update function?

Comment: Are you sure the form method is POST and not GET?

Comment: Where are you calling the function?

Comment: @SLaks.Please can you explain more. the db function is actually in the libraries.php I file that is included.

Comment: @Patrick, is it wrong to declare the createsalt function inside the update function since the intention is to update a record in the database that already has a hashed password with a sha* combination.

Comment: @dqhendricks, I am calling the function from the same page. the database is called from another page "libraries.php"

Comment: @CharlesOkaformbah are you sure that the function is being called at all? Do you have error reporting turned on, and if so, to what level? You typically wouldn't want to declare a function within another function for readability's sake, but it should not affect the way this code performs in any way. nested functions can still be called from any script on the page, and are not limited to scope.

Comment: Do your database functions do any sort of error reporting? We really can't see most of what is going on here.

Comment: @CharlesOkaformbah It is not per definition wrong to declare it inside the update function, but you might get into trouble when your update function is called multiple times. That might result in an error because it tries to redeclare the createSalt function. What is wrong with declaring the createSalt function top-level?

Comment: @dqhendricks. I turned off error reporting on the page the function is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
db(); // database function
```

It seems as if you've had forgotten to assign the return value of the function to `$conn`.

Correct should be:

```
$conn = db();
```

Comment: still having issues with it.I just edited my script to give more details about the function.

Comment: @CharlesOkaformbah This is another situation. You cannot mix mysql and mysqli/PDO. Let db() return a mysqli connection and change the rest to mysqli_query (and bind_params) ___or___ use the normal mysql_query with mysql_real_escape_string instead of parameter binding (what mysql (without i) doesn't support).

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this code at the bottom at the line before the `?>`:

```
if isset($_POST['user']) { update(); }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is just a rough example, and I have not tested it. It is here, just so you can get the picture.

**The function**

```
 function update_db($data, $update){
   $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=locahost; dbname=xxxx', 'xxx', 'xxx');
   $stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE table, SET something=? WHERE id = ? ");
   $stmt->execute(array($data, $update));

  if($stmt->rowCount() > 0){
     return 'Updated';}
  else {
     return 'Something is wrong';
    }
 }
```

**Calling it**

```
if(isset($_GET['data'])) {
$data = $_GET['data'];
$update = 'text';


echo update_db($data, $update)

}
```

Comment: I didn't know that there exists a possibility to declare normal variable like `$conn` as superglobal.

Comment: @bwoebi It is not a super global, I just put it out of lazyness. he can declare it as a global, or he could include the database, resources there

Comment: But look, this is exactly what he has done wrong in his code: not declaring $conn.

Comment: I think he might have included along the other files, but his question is how to create a function, that updates a table. Either that, or I have missed part.

Comment: yea. I wanted to know what I am doing wrong and if my code sequence is ok

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all. I have resolved the issue. the problem was with the database as the function being called couldn't access the database.